# Continous double click increases bounding box size in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, select, double-click

I am trying to create a popup using javascript whenever some text is highlighted. I have farely created it as well. But there is a bug with it as well and I am having a difficult time removing it.

The bug is when I attemp to double click any highlighted word continously the pop div size positions and size keeps increasing and ultimately goes out of page.

here is the code

*index.html*

```
//*some more blocks of text*

<div id="popup"></div> <!-- this is popup -->
```

*styles.css*

```
#popup{
  display: none;
  background-color: orange;
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1000;
}
```

*script.js*

```
function getSelectedObj() {
  var selObj = {};
  selObj.text = '';
  if (typeof window.getSelection != "undefined") {
    selObj.rect = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0).getBoundingClientRect() ;
    selObj.text = window.getSelection().toString();
  } else if (typeof document.selection != "undefined" && document.selection.type == "Text") {
    // this block not used in new versions of chrome, mozilla and IE11
    selObj.text = document.selection.createRange().text;
  }
  return selObj;
}

function doSomethingWithSelectedText() {
  var selectedObj = getSelectedObj();
  if (selectedObj.text) {
    document.querySelector('#popup').style.display = 'block';
    //console.log(selectedObj.rect);
    document.querySelector('#popup').innerHTML = selectedObj.text;
    document.querySelector('#popup').style.height = selectedObj.rect.height;
    document.querySelector('#popup').style.width = selectedObj.rect.width;
    document.querySelector('#popup').style.top = selectedObj.rect.top - 1.5*selectedObj.rect.height;
    document.querySelector('#popup').style.left = selectedObj.rect.left ;
  } else {
    document.querySelector('#popup').style.display = 'none';
  }
}

document.onmouseup = doSomethingWithSelectedText;
document.onkeyup = doSomethingWithSelectedText;
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a working example (using a snippet), but I don't see your bug. Can you point it out please ?

```js
function getSelectedObj() {
var selObj = {};
selObj.text = '';
if (typeof window.getSelection != "undefined") {
    selObj.rect = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0).getBoundingClientRect() ;
    selObj.text = window.getSelection().toString();
} else if (typeof document.selection != "undefined" && document.selection.type == "Text") {
    // this block not used in new versions of chrome, mozilla and IE11
    selObj.text = document.selection.createRange().text;
}
return selObj;
}

function doSomethingWithSelectedText() {
var selectedObj = getSelectedObj();
if (selectedObj.text) {
    document.querySelector('#popup').style.display = 'block';
    //console.log(selectedObj.rect);
    document.querySelector('#popup').innerHTML = selectedObj.text;
    document.querySelector('#popup').style.height = selectedObj.rect.height;
    document.querySelector('#popup').style.width = selectedObj.rect.width;
    document.querySelector('#popup').style.top = selectedObj.rect.top - 1.5*selectedObj.rect.height;
    document.querySelector('#popup').style.left = selectedObj.rect.left ;
}
else {
    document.querySelector('#popup').style.display = 'none';
}
}

document.onmouseup = doSomethingWithSelectedText;
document.onkeyup = doSomethingWithSelectedText;
```

```css
#popup{
display: none;
background-color: orange;
color: white;
position: absolute;
z-index: 1000;
}
```

```html
<div id="popup"></div>

Here is some text I'd like to select.
```

Comment: it was because of some other script working on the page.
Can you guide me a bit about how to show the popup like this [link](http://kenshin54.github.io/popline/)

I am not saying about the css but the static position of the popup box/ toot tip.

Comment: I think you should post another question and I'll be glad to help you on this.